# Draw a graph with 8 vertices, all of odd degree, that doesn't contain a path of length 3, or explain why such a graph doesn't exist.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

**Problem:** Draw a graph with $8$ vertices, all of odd degree, that doesn't contain a path of length $3$, or explain why such a graph doesn't exist.

**My approach**

1. What is a path of length $3$? $\implies$ Path $3$ means that there are $3$ edges $(i,j)$, $(j,k)$, $(k,l)$ that connect $j$ and $l$ (Thanks Patrick)
2. How do we prove a graph problem??? induction? inversion?

Comment: Path 3 means that there are 3 edges (i,j),(j,k),(k,l) that connect j and l

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I just edited the question

Comment: You should look the exact meaning up. In a path vertices and edges cannot repeat.

Comment: Also, you should try to look at a vertex of maximal degree in your graph and try to further construct it.

Comment: It is easy to construct a non-connected graph satisfying the properties.

Comment: So I guess it doesn't exsit by "the degree sum formula"?

Comment: With this kind of question its general a good advice to be careful if the graph should be disconnect or not (more general if it's simple or not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a graph with $8$ vertices, with one central vertex $v$ of degree $7$, and no edges other than the edges from $v$.

Then every vertex other than $v$ has degree $1$.

It's easy to see that there are no paths of length $3$.

Thus, such a graph *does* exist.

For another example, since disconnected graphs are not explicitly disallowed, consider a graph with $8$ vertices, and $4$ pairwise disjoint edges. Then every vertex has degree $1$, and there are no paths of length greater than $1$.

Comment: Alternatively, connect the 8 vertices into 4 pairs.

Comment: Yes, I also saw that.